# What is the difference between countable and uncountable infinite sets in probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

In infinite sets.  Is there a difference between  say, the natural numbers and the real numbers?

I know that there is a problem when trying to add the probabilities of hitting a certain real number which is P=zero so all probabilities are added to zero.   But the same problem occurs in natural numbers as well.  So they both aren't distributed uniformly.

My question is, is there any difference between the two sets in terms of the problem they both pose to probability?   Are they both equally difficult to be dealt with in probability?  Or is the set of natural numbers better in any regard and what is the implications of its advantage?

Comment: For a countable set, like $\mathbb N$, even though you can't have a uniform probability distribution, you can have other probability distributions defined by simply giving a non-zero probability for each individual element. That doesn't work with uncountable sets --- Only countably many points can have non-zero probabilities and, if these don't add up to $1$, then you'll have sets $X$ such that $X$ has non-zero probability while each element of $X$ has zero probability.

Comment: Thanks.   But I don't really understand.  If a natural  number has a non zero probability how could it be added to one? Since I have infinitely many such numbers.  Also, I do not understand how could one say,  that in real numbers it's zero?  What does it mean to be zero?  Just because it creates a problem in mathematics that doesn't mean it's zero.  Or please explain it intuitively,  since as far as I am concerned tho it'a extremely unlikely.   I could certainly hit randomly a real number.  Couldn't  I?

Comment: OK maybe my last comment doesn't relate so much to the question.   So I will ask if you or anyone else could elaborate more specifically on the difference between countable or uncountable sets .  Why and how could you define the set of natural numbers to be added to 1 in probability while each element is of non zero prprobability.  Please explain how it is done.  And intuitively why don't I have the same chance of hitting number 2 as I do number 565?

Comment: "*If a natural number has a nonzero probability how could it be added to one?*"  Take for example an experiment where we flip a coin repeatedly until the first tail occurs.  Let $X$ represent the number of heads that happened before the first tail.  Then $Pr(X=0)=\frac{1}{2},Pr(X=1)=\frac{1}{4},Pr(X=2)=\frac{1}{8},\dots,Pr(X=k)=\frac{1}{2^{k+1}},\dots$ and indeed $Pr(X\geq 0) = Pr(X=0)+Pr(X=1)+\dots = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\dots = 1$

Comment: "*I could certainly hit randomly a real number.  Couldn't I?*"  Consider a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.  Then we can talk about how $Pr(0.25\leq X\leq 0.75)=\int_{0.25}^{0.75}1dx = 0.5$, but for any $x\in [0.25,0.75]$ we would have $Pr(X=x)=0$.  That is not to say that it is "impossible" in the layman's meaning of the word as in the sense of it not being an outcome in the sample space... but it is so unlikely to occur that the probability of it occurring is smaller than any arbitrarily small positive real number.  It is a [null set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_set) with measure 0.

Comment: JMoravitz thank you very much.  Just I will be happy if you elaborate on just one more point.  When you guys talk about the distribution of the naturals.   What does it mean that it's not uniformly distributed?  I mean...  according to what you say .... the chances of hitting the number 7 and 745 are different.  How do you reconcile the non zero probability to be added to one not infinity.   The way you said is if we assign different probabilities to different elements.   I don't understand the logic of it tho.   How could I hit one number with higher chances than others? Please  explain thx.

Comment: In the specific example given by @JMoravitz's first comment, one "hits" a natural number$n$ by happening to get $n$ heads before the first tail (when flipping a coin repeatedly). Isn't it intuitively clear that you're more likely to have only $7$ heads before the first tail than to have $745$ heads before the first tail?

Comment: "*what does it mean that its not uniformly distributed*"  We mean that there is at least one pair of natural numbers $n,m$ for which $Pr(X=n)\neq Pr(X=m)$.  Indeed, if we did actually have every number be equally likely to choose, say with probability $p>0$ one would have $Pr(X\geq 0) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty Pr(X=n)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty p \to \infty$ which is impossible for a probability measure.  On the other hand if the probability for each was $0$ then we would have the overall sum also be zero, also impossible. This is in contrast to a probability distribution on an uncountable set.

Comment: Reiterating the point... if we have a probability distribution over a countably infinite set, we *can't* have them all be equally likely to occur.  We *must* have some be more likely than others.  There are of course *many* different probability distributions over the naturals.  I just gave one of the earlier examples someone might encounter, the geometric distribution.  One learns rather early in one's career that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}=1$, usually in calculus or perhaps even earlier than that, so you should be able to confirm that it satisfies properties to be a probability.

Comment: If $X$ has a continuous distribution, say a distribution of men's heights in inches, then how can we say $P(X = 58)=0?$ You might argue that you _know_ someone who is 58" tall. But do you know someone who is is exactly 58.000000000" tall? More sensible to say you know someone who is between 57.5" and 58.5" tall, and assign positive probability to $P(57.5 < X \le 58.5),$ maybe 0.11.